# CSS values for DIV structure setup

Tags: html, css

I need to setup the following DIV structure (See image below. It tells more than a 1000 words)

[image: Basic DIV setup]

The structure consists of 2 colums. The main column (left) has a variable width and 100% height.
The right colums has a FIXED width of 380px and 100% height.

Then inside the right column I need 3 DIVS.
The top DIV has a fixed height of 200px and must be aligned to the top.
The bottom DIV has a fixed height of 150px and must be aligned to the bottom.
The middle DIV has a variable height and must fill up the space vertically.

This is the DIV setup And the CSS I have:

```css
.main-content {
  width: 100%;
  padding: 0px;
}

.col-1 {
  width: calc(100% - 380px);
  min-height: calc(var(--vh, 1vh)*100);
  background-color: #2693FF;
  float: left;
}

.col-2 {
  width: 380px;
  min-height: calc(var(--vh, 1vh)*100);
  float: right;
}

.col-2-top {
  height: 200px;
  background-color: #00B200;
}

.col-2-middle {
  height: 100%;
  background-color: #FF8000;
}

.col-2-bottom {
  height: 100px;
  background-color: #B25900;
}
```

```html
<div class="main-content">
  <div class="col-1"></div>
  <div class="col-2">
    <div class="col-2-top"></div>
    <div class="col-2-middle"></div>
    <div class="col-2-bottom"></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Then... Column 1 and 2 should stack when the viewport width becomes less than 768px.
Column 1 on top and Column 2 below it.

Like this:

[image: Stacked DIVS]

I think I'm almost there, but I'm having problems with the height of the Main DIV and the heights and aligning of the DIV col-2 middle DIV. I also need a bit helpt to get these divs stack nicely above each each other.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have any questions how the css works, feel free to ask them in the comments.

I know the background-colors are irrelevant but they help to visualize it.

```css
.container {
  min-width: 768px;
  width: 100%;
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: calc(100% - 380px) 1fr;
  min-height: 100vh;
}

.col1 {
  background-color: dodgerblue;
}

.col2 {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}

.col2-row1 {
  height: 200px;
  background-color: orange;
}

.col2-row2 {
  background-color: forestgreen;
  height: 100%;
}

.col2-row3 {
  height: 150px;
  background-color: red;
}

@media (max-width: 768px) {
  .container {
    grid-template-columns: 1fr;
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="container">

  <div class="col1">1</div>

  <div class="col2">
    <div class="col2-row1">2</div>
    <div class="col2-row2">3</div>
    <div class="col2-row3">4</div>
  </div>

</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

I would suggest that you use [grid layout](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Grid_Layout) instead of floating around your `<div>`s, grid layout allows you to structure your layout and separate them in [`columns`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/grid-template-columns) and [`rows`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/grid-template-rows), and areas using [`grid-template-areas`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/grid-template-areas).

for `max-width:748` just add [media query](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Media_Queries/Using_media_queries),  here is how it might be implemented:

```css
body {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
}
.main-content {
  display: grid;
  background-color: #2196F3;
  grid-template-areas: 
    'main fixed-top'
    'main variable-mid-area'
    'main fixed-bottom';
  background-color: #2196F3;
  height: 100vh;
  grid-template-columns: 1fr 380px;
  grid-template-rows: 200px  1fr  150px;

}

.main-content > div {
  color: #fff;
  font-size: 30px;
  vertical-align: middle;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
}

.main {
  grid-area: main;
  background-color: #2693FC;
}


.variable-mid-area {
  grid-area: variable-mid-area;
  background-color: #FF8015;
}



.fixed-top {
  grid-area: fixed-top;
  background-color:#00B21F;
}

.fixed-bottom {
  grid-area: fixed-bottom;
  background-color: #B2590B;
}

@media only screen and (max-width: 768px) {
  .main-content {
    grid-template-areas: 
      'main'
      'fixed-top'
      'variable-mid-area'
      'fixed-bottom';
    grid-template-rows: 300px  200px 1fr  150px;
    grid-template-columns: 100%;
    height: auto;
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="main-content">
  <div class="main"> main </div>
  <div class="fixed-top"> 200 </div>
  <div class="variable-mid-area"> auto </div>
  <div class="fixed-bottom"> 150 </div>
</div>
```